# Как циклически отследить событие добавление нового элемента?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, события

Всем привет! Как циклически отслеживать событие добавление нового элемента и повесить на него обработчик? Добавление элемента происходит в списке

```
<ul class="list ">
</ul>
```

а отслеживать появление (для того, чтобы добавить) нужно его в контейнере

Comment: Самый простой способ - перенести добавление элемента и обработчик в одну функцию и добавлять элемент только через эту функцию. Другой вариант - добавление элемента опять-таки только через функцию, но вместо размещения кода обработчика в ней же генерировать какое-то своё событие. А контейнеру повесить обработчик этого события. Третий вариант уже невесёлый - повесить `setInterval`, в функции которого будет вручную проверяться не поменялся ли HTML у контейнера. Четвёртый вариант - использовать устаревшее (что вообще не рекомендуется) `DOMNodeInserted` событие и связанные с ним.

Comment: @Regent а если такой способ - не подойдет?
$.when($('.list').append($("<li>")).done(function(){}

Comment: `$.when()` принимает в качестве параметра объект типа `Deferred`, а `.append()` возвращает объекта типа `jQuery`. Это раз. Второе - `$.when()` предназначен не для обработки периодически возникающих событий. Поэтому "не подойдёт". Варианты описаны выше. Один из них с примером размещён в ответе ниже.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У вас наверняка есть функция которая добавляет элементы в список? Вставьте в конец этой функции триггер. Что-то вроде:

```
$(".list").trigger("onAddedLi");
```

И соответственно слушайте это событие:

```
$(".list").on("onAddedLi", function(){
    // Обработчик события
})
```

Comment: Пожалуй, из предложенных 4 вариантов этот действительно самый удачный и гибкий. Хотя в ситуации когда во всём коде есть один `.trigger("onAddedLi")` и один `.on("onAddedLi")`, первый вариант был бы не хуже.

Comment: @Regent может вариант и хороший, но у меня не срабатывает..

Comment: @Regent а как можно попробовать через setInterval ?

Comment: а если $(".list").change()  ?

Comment: @Вася _не срабатывает_ - это уже вопрос к вам, а не к варианту. Вот [пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4sxpd0y5/), в котором `onAddedLi` прекрасно работает. Хотите использовать событие `change` - пожалуйста, замените в примере обе строки `onAddedLi` на `change` и вперёд.

Comment: @Вася простая проверка на количество детей с помощью `setInterval`: [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/4sxpd0y5/1/).

Comment: ну, т.е. к примеру у меня есть php функция 'woocommerce_add_to_cart' , которая добавляет товар в корзину и добавляем в него триггер - я все правильно понимаю?

Comment: @Вася `woocommerce_add_to_cart` - это функция в PHP или всё же в JS?

Comment: @Regent чтоб я точно знал.. но в js есть такая запись: var data = {
    action: 'woocommerce_add_to_cart',
   };

Comment: @Вася и что происходит потом с объектом `data`?

Comment: @Regent http://jsfiddle.net/ligisayan/2nv7f5uv/ еще я там обнаружил - // Trigger event
   $( 'body' ).trigger( 'adding_to_cart', [ $thisbutton, data ] );     Может, это то, что мне нужно,да?

Comment: @Вася да, идея такая же. А [в примере](http://jsfiddle.net/4sxpd0y5/), который я размещал пару дней выше в комментариях, вместо кастомного события`adding_to_cart` используется кастомное событие `onAddedLi`, но идея абсолютно та же.

Comment: @Regent но тогда по логике должна выполнятся функция $('.list').on('added_to_cart', function() {...} а она у меня не вызывается..

Comment: или повесить на функцию $( document ).on( 'click', '.add_to_cart_button', function(e) {..} триггер нужно - да?

Comment: @Regent эхх.. ни то, ни другое не прокатывает

Comment: забыл сообщить, что setInterval конечно же решил проблему, но не так изящно - это костыль и я бы с этим смирился, если бы он не влиял на функциональность других элементов, в частности мою на карусель..

Comment: @Вася но в скинутом мною примере вызывается? Вызывается. Соответственно, либо вы неправильно скопировали пример, либо у вас где-то ещё ошибка в коде. Без полного примера кода я ничего точно сказать не могу. А ещё мы весьма увлеклись в комментариях. Попробуйте **аккуратно** всё сделать с .`trigger()` и `.on()`, и если что-то всё равно не будет - задать новый вопрос с кодом попытки и описанием что именно не так.

Comment: Вася, ну что вы так невнимательны? Событие `added_to_cart` у вас же вызывается для элемента `body` - ну и так и слушать надо на нем же!

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov о, точно! все супер! Спасибо вам большое ребята - очень выручили! надеюсь, этот разбор решения кому-то тоже пригодится)

Answer (score 3):

Это можно сделать в последних браузерах (Chrome, Mozilla, IE11) через MutationObserver:

```js
(function () {
    // select the target node
    var target = $(".list").get(0);

    // create an observer instance
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
            // mutation.mutationType будет равен "childList"
            // новый li будет в mutation.addedNodes
            alert($(mutation.addedNodes[0]).text());
        });
    });

    // configuration of the observer:
    var config = { childList: true };

    // pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
    observer.observe(target, config);

    // добавляем элементы:
    $(".list").append($("<li>new item 1</li>"));
    $(".list").append($("<li>new item 2</li>"));
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
</ul>
```

В старых - через DOM Mutation Events (не уверен насчет IE 10-, в нем вроде не работало):

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
    var element = e.target;
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(element).fadeOut(1000, function() {
            $(this).remove();
        });
    }, 2000);
});
```

Или можно взять готовую библиотеку, https://github.com/naugtur/insertionQuery (поддерживает IE10+, работает через [CSS3 Animation](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation))

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, так? Вместо 'click' естественно, может быть любое событие...

```
$('.list').on('click', 'li', function(){
  //Код
})
```

Comment: пробую через 'append' или он не работает с li?
    $('.list').on('append', 'li', function(){//Код
    })

Comment: может к li нужно класс add применять?

Comment: а я могу как-то отследить добавление селектора с помощью wait.until или его аналога и не имеющего класса li.hasClass("empty")?

Comment: append - это не событие. Событие - это "click, change и т.д.". Вам необходимо узнать основы jquery, прежде чем писать подобный код. Помимо официального ресурса [jquery](http://jquery.com) ещё рекомендую [сайт по jquery на русском](http://jquery.page2page.ru/)

Comment: спасибо, но я ухватился за возможный ваша вариант решения, но уже понял, что мне он не подойдет, т.к. 'click' мне не подходит...